# Vaccines and autoimmunity concerns

Tags: vaccination, autoimmune-disease, epidemiology

Medical papers/books exist linking vaccines to autoimmunity yet I am not able to decide whether they should be considered sound and peer reviewed scientific studies or not. Some examples are:

- ["rare reactions such as hypersensitivity, induction of infection, and autoimmunity do occur and can be severe and even fatal"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19865091)
- ["In this review of the literature, there is evidence of vaccine-induced autoimmunity and adjuvant-induced autoimmunity in both experimental models as well as human patients"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26275795)
- ["The final section covers diseases in which vaccines were known to be the solicitor – for instance, systemic lupus erythematosus"](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118663438.html)

Can anyone help me to understand whether the concern about autoimmunity is or is not scientifically supported?

Comment: I can tell you that the risk is so low that the benefits of vaccines by far outweigh the risk of such disease. Otherwise, no one would do vaccines. Whether risks actually exist and how low the probability is exactly I don't know.

Comment: Marco, diseases and medicines aren't so dissimilar. They're all poisons of a sort. You can actually die by ingesting too much water, it happens to marathon runners fairly often. The trick in medicine is in weighing pros and cons of all the options and finding the ones that create the greatest benefit with the least harm. Vaccines, like all other drugs, have risks, and like all other drugs, probably even kill people here and there, as does aspirin. But on average, the risk of dying in pain from any number of infectious diseases is significantly more likely, and significantly worse, so vaccines.

Answer (score 5):

Autoimmunity triggered by vaccination is a documented, but **rare occurrence**.  The current research shows a correlation between autoimmune conditions and elevated levels of HLA proteins. Certain HLA proteins tend to have a predilection for activating the immune system against “self” cells. ***HLA proteins also can explain why certain people are more prone to autoimmune conditions that are induced or exacerbated by vaccines.***

The risk of vaccine-related autoimmunity is by orders of magnitude lower than that of autoimmunity triggered by infectious disease. Since the latter includes vaccine-preventable infections, for most autoimmune conditions there is a **net protective effect of vaccination**.

Current evidence supports administering appropriate vaccines in the absence of specific contraindications.

---

***Sources***

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26728772
    https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27435705
    http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S104366181400139X
    https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25937813
    https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10648110
    https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Srdja_Jankovic/publication/315656865_Vaccination_and_Autoimmune_Phenomena/links/58e1ed7eaca272059ab07f9c/Vaccination-and-Autoimmune-Phenomena.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Like many health issues that are currently on the rise, anything you can potentially say is vaccine related can also easily be said to be environmental toxin related.  There is quite a bit of research on autoimmune issues as it's currently a serious cause for concern to many researchers.  It is much more common today than it was 50 years ago and they are trying to understand why & what we might be able to do to stem that increase.  This book is a great one for explaining the links between toxic exposures & why it is believed to be the major factor in autoimmune disorder. https://donnajacksonnakazawa.com/the-autoimmune-epidemic-excerpt/